# Dragtable is not working when a header has some colspan

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using http://jebaird.com/demos/dragtable/ to drag columns position but it is not working if header has some colspan. It takes only first colspan to drag the whole column.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This issue appears to already have been reported under Issues: https://github.com/jebaird/dragtable/issues/35